# Two simultaneous Textchanged Events firing in Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textchanged

When I type in the first textbox, it should run a conversion which appears in the second, and when I type in the second, it will appear in the first. However, when I type in the first textchanged event, it triggers the second, which disrupts entering in the first and vice versa. Is there a way I can disable firing the textchanged event when it is highlighted or something?

```
public void dB10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox dB10 = sender as TextBox;
        double dBV;
        int i = dB10.Text.Trim().Length;

        if (i > 0)
        {
            dBV = Convert.ToDouble(dB10.Text);
        }
        else
            return;

       UnitConverter dBConverter = new UnitConverter();

       // Controls for if various radiobuttons were clicked
        if (dBVRadio.Checked == true)
        {
            dBV = dBConverter.dBVToVolts(dBV);
            voltage.Text = dBV.ToString(); 
         }

        else if (dBuRadio.Checked == true)
        {
            dBV = dBConverter.dBuToVolts(dBV);
            voltage.Text = dBV.ToString();
        } 
    }

   public void voltage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox voltage = sender as TextBox; //V >> dB10 (dBV/dBu)

        int i = voltage.Text.Trim().Length;
        double volts;

        if (i > 0)
        {
            volts = Convert.ToDouble(voltage.Text);
        }
        else
            return;

        UnitConverter dBConverter = new UnitConverter();

            if (dBVRadio.Checked == true)
            {
                dBuRadio.Checked = false;

                volts = dBConverter.voltsTodBV(volts);
                dB10.Text = volts.ToString(); 
            }

            else if (dBuRadio.Checked == true)
            {
                volts = dBConverter.voltsTodBu(volts);
                dB10.Text = volts.ToString();
            }
    }
```

Comment: go for some flag or have some event like keypressed/keyentered, because textchange wont work here I guess, because testchange would keep executing whenever the text changes either way

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the handler of another textbox and then add it

```
public void dB10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    voltage.TextChanged-= voltage_TextChanged;
    TextBox dB10 = sender as TextBox;
    double dBV;
    int i = dB10.Text.Trim().Length;

    if (i > 0)
    {
        dBV = Convert.ToDouble(dB10.Text);
    }
    else
        return;

   UnitConverter dBConverter = new UnitConverter();

   // Controls for if various radiobuttons were clicked
    if (dBVRadio.Checked == true)
    {
        dBV = dBConverter.dBVToVolts(dBV);

     }

    else if (dBuRadio.Checked == true)
    {
        dBV = dBConverter.dBuToVolts(dBV);

    } 
   voltage.Text = dBV.ToString();
   voltage.TextChanged+= voltage_TextChanged;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `bool` variable:

```
bool escape = false;

public void dB10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(escape)
        return;

    escape = true;
    // your code
    escape = false;
}

public void voltage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(escape)
        return;

    escape = true;
    // your code
    escape = false;
}
```